# How to make a python code folder only useable by that code

Tags: python, windows, user-interface

HI I made a python gui code and it is saved in a folder named `mygui` the folder has many sub folder like `image`,`icon`,`password`,`log`,`soundeffects` and `code` so I want my python code to access the main folder as well as sub folder but I don't want an user to open file explorer and gain access to the contents of the main as well as sub folders

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Change folder permissions via https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html or in `explorer` via right-click -> Properties -> Security _tab_.